# Nancy route shows blank page

Tags: routes, nancy

I have a payment application. One of its pages is called from payment service (another website). This page is a `Nancy` route like it:

```
public PaymentModule()
{
    Get["/PaymentCallback"] = _ =>
    {
        return "Hello";
    };
}
```

External website redirects to this route but route is not executed. That mean browser shows blank page. If I select `URL` in the browser and hit `ENTER` key, it will work properly.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

External website needed `POST` method. When I changed `PaymentCallback` from `GET` to `POST` it got corrected.